# Change Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement for sqlite3 using shell script

Tags: shell, sqlite

By **[sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)** i know that The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to **1000000**. You can redefine this limit to be as large as the smaller of SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH and **1073741824**

I want to execute a sql from shell script that is large than 1000000 byte. so need to change SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH

i'm using shell script and **SQLite version 3.7.17** my os is **centos7**. 
After trying alternative way but that cannot serve my purpose. so need to change SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH. How can i do it?